# Is it possible to set geometric object color and linetype without using Selection?

Tags: vba, catia

I would like to set all the `Curve2D` objects in a drawing file color and linetype. I could loop through all of the sheets, get the views, then get the objects. However, the issue is that I cannot use the `VisProperties` or find something similar to change the color or linetype of these objects.

I can, however, use the `Selection` to do this but this is quite slow and the screen keeps flashing. I would like to check if there is a faster way or I am stuck @ using `ActivateDocument.Selection.Add`

Comment: You could try to improve the performance of the selection by deactivating the highlighting of the selected object (see _HSOSynchronized_ in the documentation)

Comment: @Shrotter, thank you. It helps but not a lot,  so I decide to manually do this step.

Comment: Consider to use _Selection.Search_ to select the curves and change _VisProperties_ at once.

Comment: Thanks, @Shrotter, I will investigate this. First time programming with CATIA.